# formula for results based on multiple column criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

in excel, have a 3,000 line report with a column where i enter the month that a product inquiry came in (Jan., Feb., etc.) & another column noting if this inquiry ended in a sale (Yes, No) - would like a formula to give me results or how many of the inquiries for each month resulted in a sale ("Yes").

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a Q&A site, not a service site, so we need to know what you have already attempted and where you are stuck. We will try to help from there. Reading **[ask]** may help you improve your question.

Comment: i have a table on separate sheet displaying the totals for the months inquires from simple formula....i cannot get the correct formula that produces result that considers the column entering a certain months totals & the column for Yes/No sale entry

Comment: Share the formula(s) you are using or have tried. We can't help you if we don't know what you are doing. Also, have you looked into using pivot tables? They are designed for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can run a countif() formula.  For example if column b had the yes/no responses, then you could do =countif(B:B,"yes")

Comment: this gives me total "yes" results for column....need to report on the number of "yes" results based on the month (entered in other column - have separate table built to view (a) all the months total inquiry results using the countif formula.....need to (b) also report on the subset of total inquiries each month that resulted in a sale

Answer (score 0):

Assume column 1 has the 3 character month name ("Jan", "Feb", etc.), and column 2 has Yes or No indicating whether the inquiry resulted in a sale or not, for example like this:

```
     1       2
1  Month    Sale?
2  Jan      Yes
3  Jan      No
4  Jan      No
5  Jan      No
6  Feb      Yes
7  Feb      Yes
8  Mar      No
9  Mar      No
10 Mar      Yes
11 Mar      Yes
12 Mar      No
```

etc.

Then put in column 4 (or anywhere, even another sheet, just fix up the formulas to point to the right place):

```
     4        5                             6
1  Month    Sales                           Percentage
2  Jan      =COUNTIFS(C1,RC[-1],C2,"Yes")   =RC[-1]/IF(COUNTIF(C1,RC[-2])=0,1,COUNTIF(C1,RC[-2]))
3  Feb
```

In column 4, select Jan and Feb then click on the lower-right corner of the selection box and drag down. Excel should automatically fill in the sequence. Then select R2C5:R13C6 and fill down. Voilá!

You should get:

```
     4        5          6
1  Month    Sales   Percentage
2  Jan        1          0.25
3  Feb        2          1
4  Mar        2          0.4
5  Apr        0          0
6  May        0          0
7  Jun        0          0
8  Jul        0          0
9  Aug        0          0
10 Sep        0          0
11 Oct        0          0
12 Nov        0          0
13 Dec        0          0
```

On edit - My first attempt was to use a pivot table, but I couldn't get it working, however (of course) *after* I posted the above I realized what I was doing wrong, so here's a pivot table that does the same thing:

[image]

The source is C1:C2.

Either solution will work, it just depends on what else you want to do with the data, and whether having to manually refresh the pivot table is a problem or not. Because the number of buckets (the months) is fixed, I might go with the formula solution to get the automatic recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot table method will work but the OP asked for a formula.
If the information is in column A & B, this formula lets you type a month in cell C1 and it counts all months that match C1 and were yes

> =COUNTIFS(A:A, C1,B:B,"Yes")